# jQuery UI loaded before Bootstrap, but still overwrite Bootstrap styles?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

I have some tooltips on my page, created as:

```
<th rel="tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Text to show in tooltip">Change to date</th>

$("[data-toggle=\"tooltip\"]").tooltip();
```

This should show the classic black bootstrap tooltip. However, it shows a different-looking tooltip. When I inspect the tooltip element, I see that all its styles are derived from jquery-ui.css, but this shouldn't be the case because jQuery UI is loaded before Bootstrap:

```
<!-- jQuery UI -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<!-- Theme Styles -->
<link href="/valera/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/valera/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Anyone have any idea why this is?

Comment: Hey can you post a fiddle or some example of your code? Could be a problem with CSS specificity.

Answer (score 0):

IT's because JQueryUI has some CSS selectors that override the ones in Bootstrap. You need to override that in your CSS to make sure that it cancels out the rule in JQueryUI. 
If you need any more help, you can post a link to a fiddle or codepen.